# Photos are not appearing wide

Tags: nikon-d5600

I am new to DSLR photography. I purchased Nikon D5600. Initially, when I used to transfer the photos on my phone using SnapBridge, the photos where not full screen but the width was comparatively more as compared to now.

I don't know which setting got changed accidentally. Now the width of the photo (when phone rotated), is even more less. It appears like a square shaped photo.

I checked the resolution and the setting is set to highest resolution. Why photos are not coming full screen?

Edited:

Even if you open this on computer using Microsoft Photos, it is not appearing full size:

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what it's like now, and post that?  I don't exactly know what you're talking about here...

Comment: @Cullub Photo added

Comment: That image appears to be a crop.

Comment: Do not crop the image. Full size images/screenshots! Did you follow my process? What was the result?

Comment: @Hueco I didn't crop. It is the one which is getting transferred to SnapBridge from camera.

Comment: @RKh We are confused because you say "appears like a square shaped photo", but the image you have uploaded is a very long rectangle — even with the black bars at the ends, the image is a panoramic aspect ratio, not at all square.

Comment: @mattdm Why those black bars appearing at the end ? I also noticed the resolution.  The camera is set to: 6000x4000 whereas when photos get transferred to device via SnapBridge, the resolution changes to 1600x1484.

Comment: But the file you've uploaded is 1365×191.

Comment: @mattdm Yes, it is the same from SnapBridge

Comment: What? 1365×191 is not the same as 1600×1484. Where did the image you upload come from? How did you generate it? How does it relate to the image you are uploading?

Comment: @mattdm I got the clue. When I connected the camera from Wifi and selected "Download Pictures" from Snapbridge, I transferred the downloaded image to PC. While downloading, it asks option "Download original size or 2 mega pixels". I downloaded the original on phone and transferred to Microsoft Photos. In Photos, it shows original resolution to 6000x4000. However, on phone, it still shows those black bars at the end. The other photos which I clicked from Phone camera, appears full screen on phone. But camera pictures when transferred on phone, appear with black bars. I am not understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is view on camera different from actual output viewed on phone?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/110582/why-is-view-on-camera-different-from-actual-output-viewed-on-phone) I'm flagging this in reverse order as the newer one seems to have more chance of guessing 'why'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to tell what your actual problem is from your question. Please revise it to give more detail. But, to give it a go...

Do not use SnapBridge and make sure that your camera is set to jpg and large. It should be shooting a full resolution image with a ratio of 2:3. Capture an image. Look at it on playback to confirm aspect ratio. Now, load the card to a computer and confirm. Everything look good so far? Great. (If not, then you've probably applied some crop/aspect ratio change in a setting. I don't shoot Nikon so can't give you more than that)

Now, use SnapBridge. Take the same image (a tripod helps in testing, otherwise just set your camera on a table for the test shots). Now, remove the memory card and upload to a computer. Is there a difference between the card file and the SnapBridge transferred file or are they the same? Is the size and aspect ratio still good or has it been cropped?

If the image has been cropped, then you need to find the setting that is doing the cropping. If the image files look good on a computer, but appear cropped on your phone - then there's nothing wrong with the camera or your settings. You need to adjust how your phone is displaying the image.

Comment: Photo sample added in original post

Answer (score 1):

The image you uploaded appears to be cropped.  If that is the exact file you are trying to view, the problem is that it is cropped.  There is insufficient information to determine why.

Try copying the file directly from the memory card, as [Hueco suggests](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/109505/75526).  If the result is not cropped, there is probably a problem with software configuration.  If the file on the memory card is cropped, it is probably a camera setting.

---

> I checked the resolution and the setting is set to highest resolution. Why photos are not coming full screen?

If your problem is related to black bars along the sides of the photo, that is normal.

DSLRs usually capture with a 3:2 aspect ratio. Most modern computers, tablets, and phone displays have 16:9 aspect ratios. Older monitors have 4:3 and 5:4 aspect ratios, so the black bars would appear along the top and bottom. Some tablets do have 3:2 aspect ratios. A couple that come to mind are Acer Aspire Switch Alpha 12 and a few Microsoft Surface Pros.

Black bars do not appear with pictures taken directly on your phone because phone cameras often have the same aspect ratio as the display on the same phone.